# ruby-on-rails use a different encoding for a specific format

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have registered `Mime::Type.register "application/postscript", :ps` in `config/initializers/mime_types.rb` and can render `*.ps.erb` templates with `render :format => 'ps'`. This works perfect. The only thing i miss to encode the output with `ISO-8859-15` encoding. All other output should output with the default encoding `UTF-8`. I tried to force the encoding but the class `OutputBuffer` protects the output-string from being modified. Is there right way to do this?

i added `.encode('ISO-8859-15')` to the buffer in the template but this did not help. The buffer is still encoded with `UTF-8`